# FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client IBM worklight 7.0 and 401 unauthorized on IBM IHS server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, worklight-server, ibmhttpserver

I have build hybrid app and deployed it on IBM mobilefirst server 7.0. App contains android service which used to send data to backend server. After updating the android application on production I am getting

```
com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAuthenticator              E FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'ap6oohvlpd3ak1dmfivsqafebp', client token:'9u7ta9r1592qmvphssfclqn2h0'.
```

and also if I check ihs server then on IHS server I am getting 401 unauthorized. I guess it is because of token which WAS is send to client but in these case token is never going back to client,I think that is the reason I am getting 401 every time and my data not going to back end.

Please help me out to solve my problem.

Comment: What exactly did you update in the android application? If you uninstall and reinstall, what is the observation?

Comment: @VivinK Nothing changed in updated android application. If I unistall and reinstall the app.Its working fine no bad token error shown. Do you know why

Comment: Appears to be a deviceid change. Did anything else change? Mobile OS /

Comment: @VivinK you mean to say Unique Device Id? given as in link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_mobile_device_provisioning.html..There is nothing changes like Mobile OS  etc. Testing on same devices with same OS version. Android version 5.0 on which problem occurs.

Comment: @VivinK is there any way to get unique device id which is used by mobilefirst? do you have any idea when its get generated while building the application?

Comment: This is generated by the client SDK , when the application runs on the device the first time.